# Across list calculations taking the average and dividing by the diag of a cov matrix in R

Tags: r

I have two separate lists I would like to make a calculation over:

How can I make the calculation `mu / diag(sigma)` ?

Each list contains 6 lists:

Mu[1]

```
$`2013 Jul`
         AAPL           AMD           ADI          ABBV             A           APD            AA            CF 
-0.0025241390  0.0038538523  0.0003136588  0.0014847319  0.0002313723  0.0006444116 -0.0010699941 -0.0013681154 
         NVDA           HOG           WMT          AMZN 
 0.0008864361  0.0008060513  0.0006894905  0.0006147082
```

Sigma[1]

```
$`2013 Jul`
               AAPL           AMD           ADI          ABBV             A           APD              AA
AAPL  0.00041664389 0.00005752017 0.00007896389 0.00002200239 0.00001116395 0.00003895595  0.000052761161
AMD   0.00005752017 0.00119570936 0.00015508211 0.00004257827 0.00013015826 0.00008786124  0.000110874525
ADI   0.00007896389 0.00015508211 0.00016835164 0.00007886595 0.00010277878 0.00006578803  0.000059832091
ABBV  0.00002200239 0.00004257827 0.00007886595 0.00031277839 0.00004903964 0.00003939989  0.000013730574
A     0.00001116395 0.00013015826 0.00010277878 0.00004903964 0.00020605392 0.00007191518  0.000074100691
APD   0.00003895595 0.00008786124 0.00006578803 0.00003939989 0.00007191518 0.00009965092  0.000052131656
AA    0.00005276116 0.00011087452 0.00005983209 0.00001373057 0.00007410069 0.00005213166  0.000148494256
CF    0.00002769930 0.00009567907 0.00008538958 0.00004723808 0.00008854491 0.00006873004  0.000087412041
NVDA  0.00004080288 0.00014291555 0.00009863768 0.00005111435 0.00009301417 0.00005779923  0.000068540074
HOG   0.00001155955 0.00014300610 0.00010598492 0.00007319286 0.00011746490 0.00007427693  0.000067448450
WMT  -0.00000378780 0.00002282687 0.00002100417 0.00002575448 0.00003714578 0.00001069815 -0.000001207622
AMZN -0.00003663661 0.00011805891 0.00010175071 0.00002949141 0.00011385205 0.00005096968  0.000038319282
                 CF          NVDA           HOG             WMT           AMZN
AAPL  0.00002769930 0.00004080288 0.00001155955 -0.000003787800 -0.00003663661
AMD   0.00009567907 0.00014291555 0.00014300610  0.000022826874  0.00011805891
ADI   0.00008538958 0.00009863768 0.00010598492  0.000021004172  0.00010175071
ABBV  0.00004723808 0.00005111435 0.00007319286  0.000025754484  0.00002949141
A     0.00008854491 0.00009301417 0.00011746490  0.000037145777  0.00011385205
APD   0.00006873004 0.00005779923 0.00007427693  0.000010698153  0.00005096968
AA    0.00008741204 0.00006854007 0.00006744845 -0.000001207622  0.00003831928
CF    0.00022714265 0.00007056718 0.00008999676 -0.000011176475  0.00006059772
NVDA  0.00007056718 0.00020920079 0.00007058210  0.000012709646  0.00008526335
HOG   0.00008999676 0.00007058210 0.00023925429  0.000021431042  0.00008949032
WMT  -0.00001117648 0.00001270965 0.00002143104  0.000068197626  0.00002355657
AMZN  0.00006059772 0.00008526335 0.00008949032  0.000023556575  0.00031175723
```

I want to divide each list by its corresponding list, such that `mu[1] / diag Sigma[1]`

Using `mus[1] / diag(Sigmas[1])` doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to divide all `mu` by `diag(Sigma)`

My Data:

Mu

```
mu <- list(`2013 Jul` = c(AAPL = -0.00252413896048252, AMD = 0.00385385230384388, 
ADI = 0.000313658814841043, ABBV = 0.00148473194650269, A = 0.000231372267065186, 
APD = 0.000644411609229898, AA = -0.00106999405402468, CF = -0.00136811540143579, 
NVDA = 0.000886436095375894, HOG = 0.000806051331850114, WMT = 0.000689490484865284, 
AMZN = 0.000614708184565435), `2013 Aug` = c(AAPL = 0.0000471064768722691, 
AMD = 0.00297250845145986, ADI = 0.00110927645875706, ABBV = 0.00186505842086247, 
A = 0.0000542259939665846, APD = 0.00186178155179209, AA = -0.000794925865044543, 
CF = -0.00109320436559941, NVDA = 0.00139874293303574, HOG = 0.000699507074667968, 
WMT = 0.000964557826996342, AMZN = 0.00100980845937234), `2013 Sep` = c(AAPL = 0.000874550640770086, 
AMD = 0.00212896308150426, ADI = 0.000297401899798995, ABBV = 0.00126327568847214, 
A = 0.00097767693668047, APD = 0.00143416399096666, AA = -0.000734440361937234, 
CF = -0.000254998800234454, NVDA = 0.00127259109916125, HOG = 0.00105093597431519, 
WMT = 0.00038339075327491, AMZN = 0.000479002073488143), `2013 Oct` = c(AAPL = 0.000682565466572836, 
AMD = 0.00313699867162714, ADI = 0.000209923665516306, ABBV = 0.000865756791407934, 
A = 0.00161631482825611, APD = 0.00168294315897343, AA = -0.000319519044240903, 
CF = 0.00096163857613333, NVDA = 0.00158604314072248, HOG = 0.00151424115101764, 
WMT = 0.00000265229900199134, AMZN = 0.00124777917896926), `2013 Nov` = c(AAPL = 0.00138847413611967, 
AMD = 0.00131189086851618, ADI = 0.000998905149605624, ABBV = 0.00053428429850944, 
A = 0.0016278252466143, APD = 0.0018596391559994, AA = 0.000727945791304539, 
CF = 0.00128641077503917, NVDA = 0.000839077531026809, HOG = 0.00128443125529569, 
WMT = -0.00000406995915300601, AMZN = 0.00279573900270221), `2013 Dec` = c(AAPL = 0.00176889092052374, 
AMD = -0.000742603775364103, ADI = 0.00044132637464973, ABBV = 0.00113925715965696, 
A = 0.00135042334177499, APD = 0.00122867453428789, AA = 0.00102055404174894, 
CF = 0.00128611035428346, NVDA = 0.000674203471055744, HOG = 0.00164877495332821, 
WMT = 0.000671450466059644, AMZN = 0.00299158521138261))
```

Sigma:

```
Sigma <- list(`2013 Jul` = structure(c(0.000416643886758763, 0.0000575201746765611, 
0.0000789638920855847, 0.0000220023900018263, 0.0000111639502490768, 
0.0000389559475190128, 0.0000527611613642388, 0.0000276992964194271, 
0.0000408028782885074, 0.0000115595509868784, -0.0000037878002746425, 
-0.0000366366098987774, 0.0000575201746765611, 0.00119570936132192, 
0.000155082111688544, 0.0000425782714446992, 0.000130158263810212, 
0.0000878612354816402, 0.000110874524552274, 0.0000956790721355811, 
0.000142915553968933, 0.000143006102651394, 0.0000228268738459166, 
0.000118058907654786, 0.0000789638920855847, 0.000155082111688544, 
0.000168351643640767, 0.0000788659479307403, 0.000102778784483304, 
0.0000657880339646833, 0.0000598320912919172, 0.0000853895841140346, 
0.0000986376834952542, 0.000105984917456237, 0.0000210041724262002, 
0.000101750712552628, 0.0000220023900018263, 0.0000425782714446992, 
0.0000788659479307403, 0.000312778387971074, 0.000049039640960627, 
0.0000393998916621414, 0.000013730573676239, 0.0000472380756047525, 
0.0000511143483915833, 0.0000731928556977193, 0.0000257544841976242, 
0.0000294914069933314, 0.0000111639502490768, 0.000130158263810212, 
0.000102778784483304, 0.000049039640960627, 0.000206053920651814, 
0.0000719151829814278, 0.0000741006909963334, 0.0000885449139074768, 
0.0000930141655227777, 0.00011746490314149, 0.0000371457765331769, 
0.000113852047489411, 0.0000389559475190128, 0.0000878612354816402, 
0.0000657880339646833, 0.0000393998916621414, 0.0000719151829814278, 
0.0000996509203523389, 0.0000521316564566408, 0.000068730039255043, 
0.0000577992258000496, 0.0000742769306657648, 0.0000106981527050766, 
0.0000509696753371964, 0.0000527611613642388, 0.000110874524552274, 
0.0000598320912919172, 0.000013730573676239, 0.0000741006909963334, 
0.0000521316564566408, 0.000148494256109656, 0.0000874120413581227, 
0.0000685400738576454, 0.0000674484501661069, -0.0000012076222555024, 
0.0000383192820636322, 0.0000276992964194271, 0.0000956790721355811, 
0.0000853895841140346, 0.0000472380756047525, 0.0000885449139074768, 
0.000068730039255043, 0.0000874120413581227, 0.000227142652461996, 
0.0000705671796000693, 0.0000899967556869206, -0.0000111764754144841, 
0.0000605977195804694, 0.0000408028782885074, 0.000142915553968933, 
0.0000986376834952542, 0.0000511143483915833, 0.0000930141655227777, 
0.0000577992258000496, 0.0000685400738576454, 0.0000705671796000693, 
0.000209200789691729, 0.0000705821034434308, 0.0000127096462767631, 
0.0000852633525054778, 0.0000115595509868784, 0.000143006102651394, 
0.000105984917456237, 0.0000731928556977193, 0.00011746490314149, 
0.0000742769306657648, 0.0000674484501661069, 0.0000899967556869206, 
0.0000705821034434308, 0.000239254290396505, 0.0000214310415786661, 
0.0000894903234052336, -0.0000037878002746425, 0.0000228268738459166, 
0.0000210041724262002, 0.0000257544841976242, 0.0000371457765331769, 
0.0000106981527050766, -0.0000012076222555024, -0.0000111764754144841, 
0.0000127096462767631, 0.0000214310415786661, 0.0000681976259943942, 
0.0000235565746471074, -0.0000366366098987774, 0.000118058907654786, 
0.000101750712552628, 0.0000294914069933314, 0.000113852047489411, 
0.0000509696753371964, 0.0000383192820636322, 0.0000605977195804694, 
0.0000852633525054778, 0.0000894903234052336, 0.0000235565746471074, 
0.000311757230578142), .Dim = c(12L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(c("AAPL", 
"AMD", "ADI", "ABBV", "A", "APD", "AA", "CF", "NVDA", "HOG", 
"WMT", "AMZN"), c("AAPL", "AMD", "ADI", "ABBV", "A", "APD", "AA", 
"CF", "NVDA", "HOG", "WMT", "AMZN"))), `2013 Aug` = structure(c(0.000266376810665656, 
0.000102646024469171, 0.0000750036597074999, -0.000000303995751271217, 
0.0000360100939425462, 0.0000378275353266367, 0.0000487484045862342, 
0.0000679946834461002, 0.0000500355701292832, 0.0000507336994179233, 
-0.00000792202496149912, 0.0000202469346414574, 0.000102646024469171, 
0.00132219539700646, 0.000176670885152745, 0.0000177889285130277, 
0.000136829989253102, 0.0000915957333247249, 0.000156124581818093, 
0.000113028117036578, 0.000158288454634329, 0.000155303358942779, 
0.0000225031359083731, 0.000121225099187987, 0.0000750036597074999, 
0.000176670885152745, 0.000166442527755379, 0.000069321830090922, 
0.000105787648289648, 0.0000802700835436298, 0.0000702926464122741, 
0.0000895483758133964, 0.000103478440044946, 0.000101589989608093, 
0.0000239852712211574, 0.000104018111503834, -0.000000303995751271217, 
0.0000177889285130277, 0.000069321830090922, 0.000293537070159334, 
0.0000543866034716202, 0.0000417070926485985, 0.0000230691125545005, 
0.0000553376914990916, 0.0000510257421229842, 0.000060135187112579, 
0.0000295028613341954, 0.000047259365960046, 0.0000360100939425462, 
0.000136829989253102, 0.000105787648289648, 0.0000543866034716202, 
0.000205602999677141, 0.0000761036455995998, 0.0000707222282933177, 
0.0000694550719063977, 0.0000861543657806432, 0.000109249602356004, 
0.000040415940369965, 0.000105845873229971, 0.0000378275353266367, 
0.0000915957333247249, 0.0000802700835436298, 0.0000417070926485985, 
0.0000761036455995998, 0.000166028134604713, 0.0000479369600434621, 
0.000070691358275638, 0.0000618900157227336, 0.0000653327169735, 
0.0000108692715624005, 0.0000538240646020979, 0.0000487484045862342, 
0.000156124581818093, 0.0000702926464122741, 0.0000230691125545005, 
0.0000707222282933177, 0.0000479369600434621, 0.000146676471399529, 
0.000087392319122003, 0.0000655668563463606, 0.0000764851514895254, 
-0.000000224667419708207, 0.000053333277012164, 0.0000679946834461002, 
0.000113028117036578, 0.0000895483758133964, 0.0000553376914990916, 
0.0000694550719063977, 0.000070691358275638, 0.000087392319122003, 
0.000334870074175067, 0.0000627866889615617, 0.0000903387885383747, 
-0.00000629306068193906, 0.0000443509252452586, 0.0000500355701292832, 
0.000158288454634329, 0.000103478440044946, 0.0000510257421229842, 
0.0000861543657806432, 0.0000618900157227336, 0.0000655668563463606, 
0.0000627866889615617, 0.000179641006950314, 0.0000862200068484314, 
0.0000127362921237457, 0.0000783747511330152, 0.0000507336994179233, 
0.000155303358942779, 0.000101589989608093, 0.000060135187112579, 
0.000109249602356004, 0.0000653327169735, 0.0000764851514895254, 
0.0000903387885383747, 0.0000862200068484314, 0.000210265957289963, 
0.0000227561029363191, 0.0000932334678023935, -0.00000792202496149912, 
0.0000225031359083731, 0.0000239852712211574, 0.0000295028613341954, 
0.000040415940369965, 0.0000108692715624005, -0.000000224667419708207, 
-0.00000629306068193906, 0.0000127362921237457, 0.0000227561029363191, 
0.0000690290825179544, 0.0000410742698618627, 0.0000202469346414574, 
0.000121225099187987, 0.000104018111503834, 0.000047259365960046, 
0.000105845873229971, 0.0000538240646020979, 0.000053333277012164, 
0.0000443509252452586, 0.0000783747511330152, 0.0000932334678023935, 
0.0000410742698618627, 0.000250913116610334), .Dim = c(12L, 12L
), .Dimnames = list(c("AAPL", "AMD", "ADI", "ABBV", "A", "APD", 
"AA", "CF", "NVDA", "HOG", "WMT", "AMZN"), c("AAPL", "AMD", "ADI", 
"ABBV", "A", "APD", "AA", "CF", "NVDA", "HOG", "WMT", "AMZN"))), 
    `2013 Sep` = structure(c(0.000260185752934072, 0.000103619179723936, 
    0.0000634795578548089, 0.0000100133552182317, 0.0000220250262024592, 
    0.0000219494081789225, 0.0000346942329143775, 0.0000575809377776677, 
    0.000041367145802818, 0.0000428076635165902, -0.0000158244437835025, 
    0.00000521865227452806, 0.000103619179723936, 0.0012673944241585, 
    0.000152976472733384, 0.0000378005016314996, 0.0000969685986015979, 
    0.0000737105823747991, 0.000142354321778133, 0.0000872222619268461, 
    0.000160096241353327, 0.000150088371960102, 0.0000308837560859658, 
    0.000108745598470934, 0.0000634795578548089, 0.000152976472733384, 
    0.000150408462743999, 0.000079759247660213, 0.0000885138969845252, 
    0.0000649836671352587, 0.0000584827231799672, 0.0000660930447584937, 
    0.0000844784678844367, 0.0000972584036669882, 0.0000256969474722734, 
    0.000098647493933917, 0.0000100133552182317, 0.0000378005016314996, 
    0.000079759247660213, 0.000274864169047915, 0.0000615682328851307, 
    0.0000470770901037539, 0.0000219282663068747, 0.0000475234958829655, 
    0.0000413072390199246, 0.0000731363896455753, 0.0000450443965576894, 
    0.0000573762356666793, 0.0000220250262024592, 0.0000969685986015979, 
    0.0000885138969845252, 0.0000615682328851307, 0.000176523662087773, 
    0.0000561686602155714, 0.0000664236361079563, 0.0000549692117098347, 
    0.000075741136659798, 0.0000965156598525872, 0.000026184697750621, 
    0.0000875440746344027, 0.0000219494081789225, 0.0000737105823747991, 
    0.0000649836671352587, 0.0000470770901037539, 0.0000561686602155714, 
    0.000166054877845329, 0.0000339760860009175, 0.0000531837705032797, 
    0.0000471605746480224, 0.0000598296627422445, 0.0000136034121909981, 
    0.0000485667771924023, 0.0000346942329143775, 0.000142354321778133, 
    0.0000584827231799672, 0.0000219282663068747, 0.0000664236361079563, 
    0.0000339760860009175, 0.000142575079902111, 0.0000693519052764993, 
    0.0000480094665590939, 0.000065347903136645, -0.00000327996456112743, 
    0.0000485182296507297, 0.0000575809377776677, 0.0000872222619268461, 
    0.0000660930447584937, 0.0000475234958829655, 0.0000549692117098347, 
    0.0000531837705032797, 0.0000693519052764993, 0.000310110134263049, 
    0.0000536511563357689, 0.0000754259552089199, -0.0000000811097667034523, 
    0.0000319649620985031, 0.000041367145802818, 0.000160096241353327, 
    0.0000844784678844367, 0.0000413072390199246, 0.000075741136659798, 
    0.0000471605746480224, 0.0000480094665590939, 0.0000536511563357689, 
    0.000171636148180971, 0.0000773510800565517, 0.00000884649959783945, 
    0.0000663738861523176, 0.0000428076635165902, 0.000150088371960102, 
    0.0000972584036669882, 0.0000731363896455753, 0.0000965156598525872, 
    0.0000598296627422445, 0.000065347903136645, 0.0000754259552089199, 
    0.0000773510800565517, 0.000214876758784993, 0.0000204948618049359, 
    0.0000893062594512058, -0.0000158244437835025, 0.0000308837560859658, 
    0.0000256969474722734, 0.0000450443965576894, 0.000026184697750621, 
    0.0000136034121909981, -0.00000327996456112743, -0.0000000811097667034523, 
    0.00000884649959783945, 0.0000204948618049359, 0.000064164048233367, 
    0.0000392366498881419, 0.00000521865227452806, 0.000108745598470934, 
    0.000098647493933917, 0.0000573762356666793, 0.0000875440746344027, 
    0.0000485667771924023, 0.0000485182296507297, 0.0000319649620985031, 
    0.0000663738861523176, 0.0000893062594512058, 0.0000392366498881419, 
    0.000224379194881233), .Dim = c(12L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("AAPL", "AMD", "ADI", "ABBV", "A", "APD", "AA", "CF", 
        "NVDA", "HOG", "WMT", "AMZN"), c("AAPL", "AMD", "ADI", 
        "ABBV", "A", "APD", "AA", "CF", "NVDA", "HOG", "WMT", 
        "AMZN"))), `2013 Oct` = structure(c(0.000292123566686645, 
    0.0000969406988711502, 0.0000668893836007142, 0.0000099274065186816, 
    0.0000284748215721311, 0.000022882750235075, 0.0000380633101574885, 
    0.0000411314728499623, 0.0000376688663077442, 0.0000474111003863584, 
    -0.00000112460418681563, 0.0000327000595372511, 0.0000969406988711502, 
    0.00127398532527367, 0.000149899215119524, 0.0000561979053940955, 
    0.0000865668501178837, 0.0000768090890301578, 0.000151259584531874, 
    0.000098026542181471, 0.000168404003363686, 0.000144156521079913, 
    0.000046259566194545, 0.000121608074675472, 0.0000668893836007142, 
    0.000149899215119524, 0.000136062535457606, 0.0000787249805446538, 
    0.0000797109525596907, 0.0000636352119601489, 0.0000608786020845465, 
    0.0000644347320981682, 0.000080503298414156, 0.0000917704812771963, 
    0.00002414276794745, 0.0000913721078266012, 0.0000099274065186816, 
    0.0000561979053940955, 0.0000787249805446538, 0.00027826724146937, 
    0.0000593461162278662, 0.0000463129963695562, 0.0000297355282473298, 
    0.0000556516465430997, 0.0000455674784183562, 0.0000732219992108158, 
    0.0000500390266254118, 0.0000679178213870244, 0.0000284748215721311, 
    0.0000865668501178837, 0.0000797109525596907, 0.0000593461162278662, 
    0.000178397899402941, 0.0000570672015532892, 0.0000627026855464551, 
    0.0000553729019737477, 0.0000699019344580214, 0.0000864322316421009, 
    0.0000273472143499778, 0.000090297038726938, 0.000022882750235075, 
    0.0000768090890301578, 0.0000636352119601489, 0.0000463129963695562, 
    0.0000570672015532892, 0.000179924651242272, 0.0000421754283487237, 
    0.0000560379031005859, 0.0000492880175681861, 0.0000537272986851459, 
    0.000020549624631709, 0.0000553564435211498, 0.0000380633101574885, 
    0.000151259584531874, 0.0000608786020845465, 0.0000297355282473298, 
    0.0000627026855464551, 0.0000421754283487237, 0.000157230636370053, 
    0.0000774402039605599, 0.0000552961992549884, 0.0000645328431120124, 
    0.00000956783507784561, 0.0000653641276604258, 0.0000411314728499623, 
    0.000098026542181471, 0.0000644347320981682, 0.0000556516465430997, 
    0.0000553729019737477, 0.0000560379031005859, 0.0000774402039605599, 
    0.000322827779721126, 0.0000538089350371367, 0.0000643129683101824, 
    0.00000529886707100804, 0.0000361157062516189, 0.0000376688663077442, 
    0.000168404003363686, 0.000080503298414156, 0.0000455674784183562, 
    0.0000699019344580214, 0.0000492880175681861, 0.0000552961992549884, 
    0.0000538089350371367, 0.00017224210711261, 0.000074693861135644, 
    0.0000114889622234819, 0.0000610186281427242, 0.0000474111003863584, 
    0.000144156521079913, 0.0000917704812771963, 0.0000732219992108158, 
    0.0000864322316421009, 0.0000537272986851459, 0.0000645328431120124, 
    0.0000643129683101824, 0.000074693861135644, 0.000198810640523596, 
    0.0000238295219137444, 0.0000923659186771322, -0.00000112460418681563, 
    0.000046259566194545, 0.00002414276794745, 0.0000500390266254118, 
    0.0000273472143499778, 0.000020549624631709, 0.00000956783507784561, 
    0.00000529886707100804, 0.0000114889622234819, 0.0000238295219137444, 
    0.0000624585357149499, 0.00003210811638617, 0.0000327000595372511, 
    0.000121608074675472, 0.0000913721078266012, 0.0000679178213870244, 
    0.000090297038726938, 0.0000553564435211498, 0.0000653641276604258, 
    0.0000361157062516189, 0.0000610186281427242, 0.0000923659186771322, 
    0.00003210811638617, 0.000219858293621821), .Dim = c(12L, 
    12L), .Dimnames = list(c("AAPL", "AMD", "ADI", "ABBV", "A", 
    "APD", "AA", "CF", "NVDA", "HOG", "WMT", "AMZN"), c("AAPL", 
    "AMD", "ADI", "ABBV", "A", "APD", "AA", "CF", "NVDA", "HOG", 
    "WMT", "AMZN"))), `2013 Nov` = structure(c(0.000239845257172422, 
    0.0000430979663815108, 0.0000187598651641953, -0.000016732587760101, 
    0.00000464906103006429, 0.0000118579396522232, 0.0000241230467151989, 
    0.0000362117393188716, 0.00000811507483268281, 0.0000193221912090245, 
    -0.00000193990644116803, 0.00000772681272043948, 0.0000430979663815108, 
    0.00131183305071473, 0.000123176150213028, 0.0000564929803660581, 
    0.0000993407262674518, 0.0000723767575309024, 0.0000614465585411526, 
    0.0000280834997043418, 0.000134185307800594, 0.000112244916626239, 
    0.0000518968505332216, 0.0000666329543339265, 0.0000187598651641953, 
    0.000123176150213028, 0.000124336778338181, 0.0000810694373153876, 
    0.0000672881389274563, 0.0000567937106095726, 0.0000581914285246649, 
    0.0000603338496140982, 0.000063688151843495, 0.0000716492770320877, 
    0.0000306075625680701, 0.0000770811620590006, -0.000016732587760101, 
    0.0000564929803660581, 0.0000810694373153876, 0.000258972823560562, 
    0.0000733042050699425, 0.0000556898688363073, 0.0000593085778997206, 
    0.0000724056027829302, 0.0000434125083916276, 0.0000690583750121357, 
    0.0000500799015020124, 0.000110202401523764, 0.00000464906103006429, 
    0.0000993407262674518, 0.0000672881389274563, 0.0000733042050699425, 
    0.000149160152643546, 0.0000509318099691717, 0.0000442179088484315, 
    0.0000420059347818132, 0.0000466671412106007, 0.0000711001673690489, 
    0.0000272989808814339, 0.0000747698504890309, 0.0000118579396522232, 
    0.0000723767575309024, 0.0000567937106095726, 0.0000556898688363073, 
    0.0000509318099691717, 0.000190497742088657, 0.0000427155956885336, 
    0.0000455879073778912, 0.0000406067558275263, 0.0000481520953440217, 
    0.000028804091895449, 0.0000619418456274028, 0.0000241230467151989, 
    0.0000614465585411526, 0.0000581914285246649, 0.0000593085778997206, 
    0.0000442179088484315, 0.0000427155956885336, 0.000218937085600004, 
    0.0000622607413966496, 0.0000411612198000009, 0.0000462606255087507, 
    0.0000386566541194825, 0.0000696421027542441, 0.0000362117393188716, 
    0.0000280834997043418, 0.0000603338496140982, 0.0000724056027829302, 
    0.0000420059347818132, 0.0000455879073778912, 0.0000622607413966496, 
    0.000292307573843276, 0.000051248406858989, 0.0000429793810662635, 
    0.0000196535662668962, 0.0000366850439658631, 0.00000811507483268281, 
    0.000134185307800594, 0.000063688151843495, 0.0000434125083916276, 
    0.0000466671412106007, 0.0000406067558275263, 0.0000411612198000009, 
    0.000051248406858989, 0.000138088873051221, 0.000048543400005292, 
    0.0000127871064306087, 0.0000407488425255562, 0.0000193221912090245, 
    0.000112244916626239, 0.0000716492770320877, 0.0000690583750121357, 
    0.0000711001673690489, 0.0000481520953440217, 0.0000462606255087507, 
    0.0000429793810662635, 0.000048543400005292, 0.000172578085376382, 
    0.0000242831193760889, 0.0000843255212989068, -0.00000193990644116803, 
    0.0000518968505332216, 0.0000306075625680701, 0.0000500799015020124, 
    0.0000272989808814339, 0.000028804091895449, 0.0000386566541194825, 
    0.0000196535662668962, 0.0000127871064306087, 0.0000242831193760889, 
    0.0000634573641892999, 0.0000298029168593479, 0.00000772681272043948, 
    0.0000666329543339265, 0.0000770811620590006, 0.000110202401523764, 
    0.0000747698504890309, 0.0000619418456274028, 0.0000696421027542441, 
    0.0000366850439658631, 0.0000407488425255562, 0.0000843255212989068, 
    0.0000298029168593479, 0.000256350587783924), .Dim = c(12L, 
    12L), .Dimnames = list(c("AAPL", "AMD", "ADI", "ABBV", "A", 
    "APD", "AA", "CF", "NVDA", "HOG", "WMT", "AMZN"), c("AAPL", 
    "AMD", "ADI", "ABBV", "A", "APD", "AA", "CF", "NVDA", "HOG", 
    "WMT", "AMZN"))), `2013 Dec` = structure(c(0.000230279463157106, 
    0.0000739874936861984, 0.0000157280663131775, 0.00000462987828026726, 
    0.0000206114218910319, 0.0000129611761359842, 0.0000389868173653423, 
    0.0000414858992643652, 0.0000323648578897082, 0.0000320710411790726, 
    0.00000891806347848395, 0.000031776016013169, 0.0000739874936861984, 
    0.000910358217087931, 0.0000973473104148583, 0.0000786211093814387, 
    0.0000653194055474513, 0.0000546391533207029, 0.0000603159653147439, 
    0.0000520804639585331, 0.000115675426147555, 0.0000973841080273414, 
    0.0000270941372962445, 0.0000654357141791052, 0.0000157280663131775, 
    0.0000973473104148583, 0.000129259278163821, 0.000084766348569258, 
    0.0000705126777081524, 0.0000561208896292504, 0.0000564091828675966, 
    0.0000530626623671728, 0.0000681075016869934, 0.0000674990402393286, 
    0.0000302291874116155, 0.0000763106937643134, 0.00000462987828026726, 
    0.0000786211093814387, 0.000084766348569258, 0.000212054778179789, 
    0.0000730554453461247, 0.0000657161439915535, 0.0000771684445452577, 
    0.0000840720405561332, 0.0000434773785729679, 0.000052855750123031, 
    0.0000478448251540904, 0.000117763955052939, 0.0000206114218910319, 
    0.0000653194055474513, 0.0000705126777081524, 0.0000730554453461247, 
    0.000187456397292226, 0.0000565202597841519, 0.0000498686589892799, 
    0.0000439946769604166, 0.000039988500672083, 0.0000609151503959029, 
    0.0000211929081591001, 0.0000766197699124352, 0.0000129611761359842, 
    0.0000546391533207029, 0.0000561208896292504, 0.0000657161439915535, 
    0.0000565202597841519, 0.00018602182742731, 0.0000468595062795141, 
    0.0000475169732357435, 0.0000362503848754728, 0.0000419252324694322, 
    0.0000291488611134949, 0.0000594723603879329, 0.0000389868173653423, 
    0.0000603159653147439, 0.0000564091828675966, 0.0000771684445452577, 
    0.0000498686589892799, 0.0000468595062795141, 0.000304097769076748, 
    0.0000700460175967659, 0.0000488003174518793, 0.000052762294765492, 
    0.0000492369153360001, 0.0000928979456706546, 0.0000414858992643652, 
    0.0000520804639585331, 0.0000530626623671728, 0.0000840720405561332, 
    0.0000439946769604166, 0.0000475169732357435, 0.0000700460175967659, 
    0.000304866512848356, 0.0000738215916107247, 0.0000465489851285226, 
    0.0000271263843128049, 0.0000501269682073041, 0.0000323648578897082, 
    0.000115675426147555, 0.0000681075016869934, 0.0000434773785729679, 
    0.000039988500672083, 0.0000362503848754728, 0.0000488003174518793, 
    0.0000738215916107247, 0.000162233752690276, 0.0000502553368280014, 
    0.0000137595510705426, 0.0000512113620658841, 0.0000320710411790726, 
    0.0000973841080273414, 0.0000674990402393286, 0.000052855750123031, 
    0.0000609151503959029, 0.0000419252324694322, 0.000052762294765492, 
    0.0000465489851285226, 0.0000502553368280014, 0.00013718772750878, 
    0.0000228350667384559, 0.0000758234480474619, 0.00000891806347848395, 
    0.0000270941372962445, 0.0000302291874116155, 0.0000478448251540904, 
    0.0000211929081591001, 0.0000291488611134949, 0.0000492369153360001, 
    0.0000271263843128049, 0.0000137595510705426, 0.0000228350667384559, 
    0.0000576228386874623, 0.0000322290121890619, 0.000031776016013169, 
    0.0000654357141791052, 0.0000763106937643134, 0.000117763955052939, 
    0.0000766197699124352, 0.0000594723603879329, 0.0000928979456706546, 
    0.0000501269682073041, 0.0000512113620658841, 0.0000758234480474619, 
    0.0000322290121890619, 0.000269472977855512), .Dim = c(12L, 
    12L), .Dimnames = list(c("AAPL", "AMD", "ADI", "ABBV", "A", 
    "APD", "AA", "CF", "NVDA", "HOG", "WMT", "AMZN"), c("AAPL", 
    "AMD", "ADI", "ABBV", "A", "APD", "AA", "CF", "NVDA", "HOG", 
    "WMT", "AMZN"))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `Map` where we pass the input as the 'mu' and 'Sigma' and divide the corresponding `list` element of 'mu' with `diag` of the element of 'Sigma'

```
Map(function(x, y) x/diag(y), mu, Sigma)
```

---

Or another option is to loop over the sequence of 'mu' in `lapply`, extract (`[[`) the elements and divide

```
lapply(seq_along(mu), function(i) mu[[i]]/diag(Sigma[[i]]))
```

Or with `base R`

```
out <- vector('list' length(mu))
for(i in seq_along(out)) out[[i]] <- mu[[i]]/diag(Sigma[[i]])
```

---

Or using `map2` from `purrr`.  All the above mentioned functions are from `base R`

```
library(purrr)
map2(mu, Sigma, ~ .x/diag(.y))
```

Comment: Thanks! How would the corresponding `map` (lowercase)  function be applied? I seem to use this version more than `Map`.

Comment: @user113156  as there are two lists, you can use `map2`  (updated the post)

Comment: `map2(.x = mus, .y = Sigmas, function(x, y) x/diag(y))` - same as what I just managed to get. Thanks again!

Comment: I will go with your `map2(mu, Sigma, ~ .x/diag(.y))` since it makes a little more sense to me.

Comment: @user113156  Yes, the `function(x)` and `~` is a compact version of that anonymous function call